# Use RegEx and .replace to substitute text with user input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace, jsfiddle

I'm new to jQuery and stumbled on the concept of RegEx with .replace to make nifty text replacements.

In my form, I have some checkboxes that trigger text to appear in a textarea. There are also some user input areas as  fields.

How can I use this jQuery to substitute a portion of text in *certain* checkboxes with the user input, but not in others? I figure using an if/else argument to trigger the RegEx and replace is key, but I don't know how to incorporate the rest?

Here is a mockup of my form:

> ```
> <div style="width: 500px;"><br>
> Static options:<br>
> <label id="_comLine100"><input id="comLine100" name="comLines" type="checkbox"> OPTION1 </label> <br>
> <label id="_comLine101"><input id="comLine101" name="comLines" type="checkbox"> OPTION2 </label> <br>
> Options which can be modified by user text:<br>
> <label id="_comLine102"><input id="comLine102" name="comLines" type="checkbox"> OPTION3 </label> <br>
> <label id="_comLine103"><input id="comLine103" name="comLines" type="checkbox"> OPTION4</label>  <br>
> </div>
> <br>
> <input id="usrinput1" size="50" placeholder="Enter something to replace the word Text">
> <br><br>
> <form>
> <input onclick="javascript:this.form.outPut2.focus();this.form.outPut2.select();"
> ```
>
> value="Select all" type="button">

**EDIT** Here is my new script, based on suggestions below:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
var comLines = {
comLine100: 'Text for option1 \n',
comLine101: 'Text for option2 \n',
comLine102: 'Text for option3 \n',
comLine103: 'Text for option4 \n'
};

var mytextbox = document.getElementById('outPut2');
var chosenComm = null;

var Inputs = document.getElementsByName("comLines");
for (var i = 0; i < Inputs.length; i++) {
    Inputs[i].onchange = function() {
        chosenComm = this;
        printComment();        
    };
    }

function printComment(){
    if(chosenComm !== null){
        var chxbox=chosenComm.id;
        var uinput = document.getElementById('usrinput1');
            if(uinput.value!=="" && (chxbox=="comLine102" || chxbox=="comLine103")){
                mytextbox.value += comLines[chosenComm.id].replace(/Text/, $('#usrinput1').val()) + "\n";
                // resets the radio box values after output is displayed
                chosenComm.checked = false;
                // resets these variables to the null state
                chosenComm = null;
            }
            else {
                mytextbox.value += comLines[chosenComm.id] + "\n";
                // resets the radio box values after output is displayed
                chosenComm.checked = false;
                // resets these variables to the null state
                chosenComm = null;
            }
    }
}

});
```

See my JSfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bENAY/2/

Now works as I wanted. Thanks to Eric S for the explanations and guidance!

Comment: You mention jQuery in your question, but you haven't tagged this as a jQuery question nor have you used any in your example? What text are you wanting to find and replace when the checkboxes are checked?

Comment: Sorry, I added jQuery as a tag. You are right, I haven't shown the jQuery I have used, which is mostly some design elements to slide divs up and down. I've been reading through this site and others, and am trying to incorporate some jQuery elements in my form. I'd like, in this example, when someone clicks boxes 3 or 4, to have the word 'Text' in the output replaced with whatever is entered in the input field. Is this type of substituion within the capability of .replace?

Comment: [RegExp is a meta-language](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) with a version baked into Javascript. It's unrelated to jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is replace:

```
mytextbox.value += comLines[chosenComm.id] + "\n";
```

with

```
mytextbox.value += comLines[chosenComm.id].replace(/Text/, $('#usrinput1').val()) + "\n";
```

The `replace` call looks for the regex in the slashes and replaces the match with the value after the comma.

`$('#usrinput1').val()` is using jQuery to find the dom element with ID of `usrinput1` and then getting the value of it (since it's an input, it gets whatever the user has entered).

---

The more complete answer would mention that you probably should embrace jQuery more:

- Replace the `window.onload` call with a `$(document).ready(function(){...})` call.
- Consider replacing the `document.getElementById` with `$('#outPut2')`
- Consider replacing the `document.getElementsByName` with `$(input[name=commLines])` or adding a class of `comm-lines` to all of those items and using `$(.comm-lines)`
- Consider using jQuery's `on` function to bind the event handlers for both the inline button handlers (use a passed in function to the `on` call) and the Inputs[i].onchange calls.

Sorry if this sounds overly judgmental, just trying to suggest a more standard and less error-prone solution.

Still requires some tweaking, but something along the lines of this:

```
$('.comm-lines').on('change', printComment);
```

---

Also, I'm sure this is just a simplified example of what you're trying to accomplish, but you might consider using links or buttons instead of checkboxes.  Your use of checkboxes doesn't really follow the expected experience your users have learned when using checkboxes on the web.  A link more closely matches the experience most users know, and so provides less surprise to them.  (Less surprise means happier users, less learning on their part and more usage.)

Comment: Eric, thanks for that nicely descriptive answer. Very educational indeed. also, thanks for the tips to improve my form code. this project was initially meant for me to learn HTML and javascript, so much of my code, as you suspected, is not as elegant as it could be if I were to use jQuery. As I'm learning jQuery now, I will try to incorporate your suggestions, since they seem to be easier to scale than what is in my current form.

Comment: One more question, by using your code suggestion, it would replace the generated text in every instance - **not just if certain checkboxes are used**. Am I correct that I should include an if/else argument that uses your code if boxes 3 & 4 are checked, but the original code if boxes 1 or 2 is checked?

Comment: Yes, you could use an if/else for that.  If there is a huge amount of different behavior in the two cases, you might consider creating two different handler functions and just registering the correct one for each case (simplifies the code a bit).  But in this simple example, if/else is probably the best bet.